# What is the PATH environment variable and how do I set it up to use the Android SDK?

Tags: macos, terminal, android

I'm a mac noob, and a terminal noob.

I'm used to installing things in Windows, and now I'm trying to set up Eclipse with the Android SDK on Mac and I'm having some trouble.

I downloaded Eclipse and stuck it in a folder I called Android, then downloaded the Android SDK and stuck it in that folder as well. The next step of [these](http://peter.boctor.net/2010/12/02/installing-the-android-sdk-on-mac-os-x/) instructions says this:

> Update your PATH environment variable to know about the Android tools.
>   There are different ways of setting your default PATH variable. I use ~/.bash_login but ~/.bash_profile also works. The Android tools are in the tools directory of the Android SDK. So this is what I added to .bash_login:
>   export PATH=$PATH:/Android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools

I have absolutely no idea what any of that means. Can someone help to dumb it down a little for me? That instruction presupposes *way* too much Mac/unix knowledge on my part.

Comment: My answer in StackOverFlow to an upgrade question where path gets changed might help as well. [Android/iOS issue fix in MACOSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080325/cordova-and-setting-android-using-command-line/20286967#20286967)

Answer (score 10):

The `PATH` environment variable is simply an order list of directories over which (typically) executables are searched for and run. In short, to get you through the setup you'll need to edit `/Users/<username/.bash_profile` to include

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools
```

This is the most painless way to do that. **Note, this assumes that you have the same SDK install path. Modify the text to suit otherwise.**

1. Open up a Terminal window (don't cringe).  Use Spotlight ( <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> ) and start typing "terminal".  Hit return when you see it highlighted.
2. Copy and paste the following into the terminal window that opens up and hit enter.

`echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/Android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools' >> ~/.bash_profile`

That's it. If you already have a `.bash_profile`, this will add that line to the end of the file.  If you don't already have one, it will create one for you.

Comment: However this does not work for GUI apps